# Normalization: how to avoid zero standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy

Have the following task:

> Normalize the matrix by columns. From each value in column subtract average (in column) and divide it by standard deviation (in the column). Your output should not contain nan (caused by division by zero). Replace Nans with 1. Don't use if and while/for.

I an working with numpy, so I wrote the following code:

```
def normalize(matrix: np.array) -> np.array:
    res = (matrix - np.mean(matrix, axis = 0)) / np.std(matrix, axis = 0, dtype=np.float64)
    return res
matrix = np.array([[1, 4, 4200], [0, 10, 5000], [1, 2, 1000]])
assert np.allclose(
    normalize(matrix),
    np.array([[ 0.7071, -0.39223,  0.46291],
              [-1.4142,  1.37281,  0.92582],
              [ 0.7071, -0.98058, -1.38873]])
)
```

The answer is right.

However, my question is: how do I avoid division by zero? If i have a column of similar numbers, I'll have standard deviation = 0 and the Nan value in result. How do I solve it? Would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task specifies to avoid `nan` in the output and replace `nan` that occur with 1. It does not specify that intermediate results may not contain `nan.` A valid solution can be to use `numpy.nan_to_num` on `res` before returning:

```
import numpy as np
def normalize(matrix: np.array) -> np.array:
    res = (matrix - np.mean(matrix, axis = 0)) / np.std(matrix, axis = 0, dtype=np.float64)
    return np.nan_to_num(res, False, 1.0)
matrix = np.array([[2, 4, 4200], [2, 10, 5000], [2, 2, 1000]])
print(normalize(matrix))
```

yields:

```
[[ 1.         -0.39223227  0.46291005]
 [ 1.          1.37281295  0.9258201 ]
 [ 1.         -0.98058068 -1.38873015]]
```